# C# Remove control that has not yet been added

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

In C# Windows Forms i am creating some dynamic controls:

```
TextBox field = new TextBox();
DateTimePicker field2 = new DateTimePicker();
CheckBox field3 = new CheckBox();
```

Based on some if statements that run after this, i will need to remove 2 of the 3 controls even before they get added to the form.
If i try this

```
Controls.Remove(field);
Controls.Remove(field3);
```

It doesnt work, presumably because they arent actually controls yet. So how else can i destroy them?
The reason i need to remove them is because afterwards in the case above, I havent deleted field2 because i need to keep that DateTimePicker and i am going to rename it 'field'.

Answer (score 5):

Your code creates the controls but does not add them to the form.

The controls will not be added to your form until you add them to your form's `Controls` collection (or a `Controls` collection of a child control).

Since you haven't added them to the form, you can't remove them from the form. And it would make no sense if you could.

Just don't add them to the form if you don't need them. Or, better yet, just don't create them in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do anything.

Once the object falls out of scope and is not referenced then it will be eligible for garbage collection and will be disposed at some point.

However, it would be a much better design if you didn't create the controls you don't need in the first place.

What you name you give an object is independent of the name of the variable you use to hold a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

you will not be able to remove these controls visibly as these controls are not a part of your windows from. hence only possible way is set the variable to null

```
field  = null;
field3 = null;
```

hope this will work for you;

if these controls already in the windows forms you can use the

```
 Controls.Remove("NameOfTheControl");
```

or just ignore them and continue your work garbage collector will do this job for you.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Turns out this isnt going to be as easy as hoped.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned from others you first need to add them to a controll collection before you can remove them from a controll collection :-)

also it is possible to trigger the garbagecollector to 'destroy' your objects: [garbagecollector](http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_FAQ%3a_How_can_I_force_garbage_collection%3F)